# aptana studio 3 and android

Tags: android, aptana

I understand unix is one of the OS systems supported  by aptana studio 3. Q: so can you download and use aptana studio 3 on an android device (as android OS is unix based)?

Answer (score 1):

Android's kernel is based on Linux - but when it comes to running apps Android can't be more different. It has it's own run-time and etc. The answer is no.